# Why FindByCode return null Object?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a web App with Spring. For persistence I use Hibernate and JPA. Now the problem I need to do a search based on a column. Attached you will find the code.

```
@Repository
public interface SchoolRepository extends JpaRepository<School, Long>{

    public School findById(long id);

    
    public School findByCodice(String valore);
    
}

// in Service class
public School getSchoolFromCode(String code) {
    return this.schoolRepository.findByCodice(code);
}
```

As written it does not work. That is, the repository method returns null.
now if I pass the string directly, then it works

```
public School getSchoolFromCode(String code) {
    return this.schoolRepository.findByCodice("432423SCHOOL867s");
}
```

Comment: It's very likely that your original method calls `getSchoolFromCode(code)` with a different value than `"432423SCHOOL867s"`.

Comment: Share your **Entity** too. I guess `findByCodice` causes trouble in the repository.